# Implementing Camera Movement and Rotation in 3D Game Engine

Tags: 3d, mathematics, camera, graphics, projection

Apologies in advance for any mistakes on terminology, I'm really really new to this

I'm completely new to 3d (and it's maths) but as a personal exercise I'm doing my own game engine that displays a simple wireframe.

I've implemented rotate (x, y and z), orthogonal, isometric, perspective projection matrices (column major) and a look_at function.

I've got a list of points and my rudimentary pipeline (on keypress) is as follows:

1. get original points
2. scale
3. rotate_x
4. rotate_y
5. rotate_z
6. look_at(cam,target,up)
7. projection
8. translate to centre of the window
   It works fine with hardcoded camera and target coordinates

However I want to be able to:

1. move the camera up/down/left/right in the same plane I'm currently at.
2. To be able to rotate that plane around the z axis
3. and to bring the plane the camera is closer or farther from the z axis
   But I have no Idea how to do that.

The reason I want to rotate around the z axis and not the y is because I haven't implemented any coordinate system and the hardcoded camera and target values are for an isometric projection.

How can I do this?